# Display grid on fieldset and legend behaves unusually on FireFox and Chrome?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS display grid, but it doesn't appear the way I expect. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <style>
                legend {display:block;}
                label {display:none;}
                fieldset, .fieldset-header {
                        display:grid;
                        grid-template:50px / 300px 100px 100px 100px;
                }
                label {display:none;}
                .fieldset-header span:nth-child(n+2) {text-align:center;}
        </style>
        <body>
        <div class="fieldset-header">
                <span>Question</span>
                <span>Bad</span>
                <span>Average</span>
                <span>Good</span>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
                        <legend>How was the hamburger?</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="q1-bad" name="q1" /><label for="q1-bad">Bad</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="q1-average" name="q1" /><label for="q1-average">Average</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="q1-good" name="q1" /><label for="q1-good">Good</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
                        <legend>How was the soft drink?</legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="q2-bad" name="q2" /><label for="q2-bad">Bad</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="q2-average" name="q2" /><label for="q2-average">Average</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="q2-good" name="q2" /><label for="q2-good">Good</label>
        </fieldset>
        </body>
</html>
```

In FireFox, it looks like this:

[image]

In Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Why won't the items display as grid?

**Temporary Bandaid Solution**

For now, I'm going to cheat by wrapping a `<div>` around the legends, inputs and labels like this:

```
<style>
        fieldset div, .fieldset-header {
                display:grid;
                grid-template:50px / 300px 100px 100px 100px;
        }
</style>
<fieldset>
        <div>
                <legend>How was the soft drink?</legend>
                <input type="radio" id="q2-bad" name="q2" /><label for="q2-bad">Bad</label>
                <input type="radio" id="q2-average" name="q2" /><label for="q2-average">Average</label>
                <input type="radio" id="q2-good" name="q2" /><label for="q2-good">Good</label>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

Now I get the behaviour I want:
[image]

Would be great if someone can tell me what I did wrong with my CSS grid in my initial approach?